# In pyspark generate minimum value for a window partition based on two column value, variable and consecutive negative values

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, pyspark

Created a rdd, having column 'a' which has a mix of positive and negative values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"b": ['A','A','A','A','B', 'B','B','C','C','D','D', 'D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D'],
                   "Sno": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                   "a": [3,-4,2, -1, -3, -1,-7,-6, 1, 1, -1, 1,4,5,-3,2,3,4, -1, -2],
                   "pos_neg": ['false','true','false','true','true','true','true','true','false','false','true','false','false','false','true','false','false','false','true','true'],
                   "neg_val_count":[0,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]})

df2=spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

the column 'pos_neg' represents if fields in 'a' is positive or negative, if negative it is true. 'neg_val_count' is counter for negative values within the fields for variable 'b'. Every time the variable 'b'changes the counter resets and consecutive negative values are taken as single. Hence for variable 'B' (in column 'b') counter is one even though there are three negative values.

I would like to generate a column which  will have the minimum value for a combination of variable in 'b' (say A) and value in 'a' (for true cases between two false). for instance for first combination of 'A' and true, the value will be -4 (it is surrounded by false),for second combination of 'A' and true value will be -1, for B there are three consecutive true so the value will be least of them as -7. Basically consecutive negative values are taken as one and minimum is taking out of them. Expected value refers to the outcome required

```
    b  Sno  a pos_neg  neg_val_count   expected value
0   A    1  3   false              0        3
1   A    2 -4    true              1       -4
2   A    3  2   false              1        2
3   A    4 -1    true              2       -1
4   B    5 -3    true              1       -7
5   B    6 -1    true              1       -7
6   B    7 -7    true              1       -7
7   C    8 -6    true              1       -6
8   C    9  1   false              1        1
9   D   10  1   false              0        1
10  D   11 -1    true              1       -1
11  D   12  1   false              1        1
12  D   13  4   false              1        4
13  D   14  5   false              1        5
14  D   15 -3    true              2       -3
15  D   16  2   false              2        2
16  D   17  3   false              2        3
17  D   18  4   false              2        4
18  D   19 -1    true              3       -2
19  D   20 -2    true              3       -2
```

I Tried using the following but it is not working, any support in this regard will be great.

```
w3 = Window.partitionBy('b','pos_neg').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0).orderBy('Sno')

df2.withColumn('new_col', F.min('a').over(w3))
```

Comment: Could you please add the expected values of `new_col` for your example? This will cover some cases which you haven't currently mentioned in your describtion.

Comment: @cronoik I have added the expected outcome column. Basically negative values for 'a' (true condition) are to be analysed (false values can be kept as it is). In case there is only one negative value (between two positives), the same number will be carried over. Incases where there are consecutive negative numbers, the minimumis to be selected. Hope that adds a little more clarity

Comment: @cronoik, another way which I could think was, I firost create a column which has concated column 'b' and 'pos_neg' and then add a a serial number (may be using cumcount) every time the text changes in the concatenated column. After that I can groupby and get the min value for each of the combination.                          I am okay if there is only one row per combination (column 'b' and 'pos_neg') as long as it highlights the least negative value